# Win 10 + Git - unable to create file - permission denied

Tags: windows, git, permissions, permission-denied

This is really not a duplicate question. I tried few solutions like `reset head^` , `git checkout -- <file>`,... but this does not solve my problem. The problem is that I can not revert the index.php file from "Changes not staged for commit" from git status because it throws me an error:

> **Unable to create file www/index.php: Permission denied during executing git "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c
>   core.quotepath=false checkout HEAD -- www/index.php**

I dont understand what is wrong with that. I am an admnistrator, console runs as administrator.. I have all permissions to do this so what permission I need? What the hell is wrong? Help me please I am in the end.

Comment: First of all, you should never run git in administrator mode. If you have to, you have done something wrong. In regards to the error - is there anything that could block that? Like rebase or merge in progress?

Comment: I don't think there is merge or other problem in Git. This is common situation where I need to revert deleted file.

Comment: Then try different approach `git checkout HEAD^ filename`

Comment: I tried it. The same error.

Comment: Oh sorry, did not notice. I am out of my known options here then.

Comment: I have it. Look at the answer.

Comment: Try to pull like this `git pull origin branch --no-edit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Git error - permission denied in this case has been caused by the incriminated file was open in other process. The solution was to shut down all the apps except one console, then run `git checkout -- www/index.php` and everything works as excepted without any trouble.

Answer (score 3):

When I did git checkout -- www/index.php this didn't work for me so My problem was happening because the antivirus had moved my file www/index.php to the **virus trunk** (**baúl de virus**)