# unable to create file when rewriting history

Tags: git

I'm using the following command

```
   git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f 
   ZeusSRC_Hardware_RPi_image_Raspberry Pi_außen_20.05.2019.zip"
```

Git then starts working, but at some point:

```
  Rewrite 2947a6eacb2fdb761127a58e77db9a988f9092c9 (194/808) (305 seconds 
  passed, remaining 965 predicted)
```

I get the following error:

```
   error: unable to create file 
   ZeusSRC/Frontend/Wetter/Wetter_Dashboard.php: Permission denied
   Could not checkout the index
```

First, Im confused why exactly this file is the problem. I didnt make any changes to it, after all I'm only trying to remove the file from the command. 
Second, I wonder whether it could be a problem with the master branch which is protected (at least on the remote side, according to the gitLab webinterface)?

AFAIK, the command Im using shoudl NOT affect other branches than the one I'm currently on when executing the command. For this to happen, I would have to use the 
       --all 
option right? And since I'm not on the feature branch, this "protected" status of master shouldnt make much of a difference for the feature branch I'm on, right?

So I wonder what I am missing/doing wrong. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `git checkout -- ZeusSRC/Frontend/Wetter/Wetter_Dashboard.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win 10 + Git - unable to create file - permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782925/win-10-git-unable-to-create-file-permission-denied)

Comment: What OS are you using? `Permission denied` means just what it says on a Unix/Linux-like system, and given that `git filter-branch` is doing the tree-filter in a temporary directory that `git filter-branch` *creates*, that should never happen (except maybe after filter-branch finishes and goes to `git checkout` the result).

Comment: @torek Im running it on Win10.

Comment: In that case, see the linked question about Windows: the permission denied problem is likely due to some other process holding files open inappropriately. I avoid Windows and hence avoid the problem entirely but I understand some antivirus programs are ill-behaved and cause sporadic errors like this (with the apparent randomness having to do with just how hard your system is working, which creates races: will the antivirus finish and get out of the way before the program you're running tries to use a file, or not?).